# Why is EPPlus Calculate() slow when evaluating 4000 rows of formulas?

Tags: excel, epplus

EPPlus 4.1 is taking 2 seconds to calculate 4000 formulas of a named range.
Each row is a simple formula for test purposes (=$D$8+I14) - the actual formula
uses MATCH and VLOOKUP, and takes 30 seconds each time.
We recalculate 232 times, iterating through a set of inputs.

Without changing the spreadsheets, are there any ideas to improve performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would try using the EPPLUS Range calculate method rather than workbook calculate: but I am not sure how EPPLUS handles dependencies with Range calculate and whether it follows a range calculate with an automatic calculation - can't find any relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a large workbook/worksheet and you only want to calculate a specific range, Range calculate can improve performance. All dependencies within the specified range are resolved and formulaes not referenced from cells within the range are ignored.

You can also try to attach EPPlus formula logger to your calculation and see if there are any exceptions thrown during the calcluation, this could affect performance. How to add a logger is described on this page (in the "Trouble shooting/Logging" section): https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=About%20Formula%20calculation&referringTitle=Documentation